# How store JSON response and save into JSON file

Tags: swift3, readfile, file-handling, swifty-json, writefile

I am using SwiftyJSON to read the API response.

I want to store the JSON response locally in user device by creating JSON file for offline.

My function which returns create JSON:

```
 Alamofire.request(HostURL)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                debugPrint("getCourseDataFromCourseId: Error while fetching tags \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                failure(response.result.error! as NSError)
                return
            }

            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                debugPrint(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            guard let json = response.result.value else {
                debugPrint("JSON Nil")
                return
            }

            let swiftJson = JSON(json)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then now you simply need to get data from the `JSON` and then use `write(to:)` method of `Data` to store `JSON` response in `DocumentDirectory`

```
if let data = try? json.rawData() {
    let fileUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                  .appendingPathComponent("Sample.json") // Your json file name
    try? data.write(to: fileUrl)
}
```

**Edit:** Now later when you want to read `JSON` from this file access it this way.

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) {
    let json = JSON(data: data)
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm new in iOS what s fileURL in getting the json file?